# unsupported operand type for datetime.now and int

Tags: python, django

I want to compute elapsed time from `request.session['SESSION_START_TIME']` to `datetime.datetime.now()`. The way I store datetime in `request.session['SESSION_START_TIME']` is:

```
request.session['SESSION_START_TIME'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

The way I want to compute elapsed time is:

```
diff = datetime.datetime.now() - request.session['SESSION_START_TIME']
```

But as a result I get this error message `unsupported operand type for -: datetime.now and int`. I guess the solution is to somehow convert values stored in session, but I do not know how.

Comment: Please, do not ask me why I do not use Django models/views, but instead use my own session routines.

Comment: You can use [`datetime.timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) and [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your session stores datetime objects as seconds since the UNIX epoch; probably because `datetime` objects themselves are not serialisable.

Convert back to a `datetime` object first:

```
start_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(request.session['SESSION_START_TIME'])
diff = datetime.datetime.now() - start_time
```

You may want to look into [*Session serialisation*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization) in the Django documentation if you want to handle `datetime` objects transparently.